# What is probability that a line joining two randomly selected coordinates from set form an angle $45°$ with one of axes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms

What is probability that a line joining two randomly selected coordinates from a set form an angle $45°$ with one of the axes?

For example, if we have set of coordinates $$\{(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4)\}$$ then, if my calculations is correct, the probability would be $0.125$

How I calculated this:
Number of ways to select coordinates is $4^2=16$ because even the same coordinates can be selected. To line form an angle $45°$ with one of axes, the slope of line have to be $1$ or $-1$. Out of these $16$ ways only $2$ have slope $1$ or $-1$ so probability is $\frac{2}{16} = 0.125$.

I am programming an algorithm that computes this probability but the algorithm have to check slope of every combination of coordinates so my question is:
Is there any other/faster way to compute this probability?

EDIT: I don't know if it helps, but coordinates will be only integers.

EDIT 2: Range of coordinates is from $-100000$ to $100000$. Number of coordinates will be no more than $10000$. Also probability will be computed to $6$ decimal places.

Comment: Partial answer. You don't have to check any pair for which the $x$ or $y$ coordinates agree, since those lines are parallel to the axes. If the set of possible points makes it easy to determine that then you save a little.

Comment: Do you have a bounds on how big the coordinates will get? Also, you don't have to compute the full slope, it is enough to check that $y_2 - y_1 = \pm (x_2 - x_1)$, which may help with doing simulations faster.

Comment: @spyr03 Yes I have. See edited question.

Comment: What's the upper bound of acceptable time complexity?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco My program has currently time complexity $O(\frac{n(n-1)}{2})$ where $n$ is number of coordinates so something faster than that especially with large $n$. I don't know maybe something like $O(n \log n)$  would be fine (if it's possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any two distinct points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ to form a $45^\circ$ angle with two axes, the equivalent condition is$$
x_1 + y_1 = x_2 + y_2 \ \text{or}\ x_1 - y_1 = x_2 - y_2. \tag{1}
$$
Note that to compute the probability, it suffices to count the number of pairs satisfying (1) and then divide it by $\binom{n}{2}$. The algorithm below counts the number of pairs $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ such that$$
x_1 + y_1 = x_2 + y_2,
$$
and there is an analogous algorithm that counts the number of pairs $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ such that$$
x_1 - y_1 = x_2 - y_2,
$$

Suppose there are $n$ distinct points `(x[1], y[1]), …, (x[n], y[n])`.

**Step1:** Compute `a[i] = x[i] + y[i]` for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$. The time complexity of this step is $O(n)$.

**Step 2:** Sort array `a`. By using merge sort, the time complexity of this step is $O(n \ln n)$.

**Step 3:** Count the multiplicity of each `a[i]`. Suppose distinct values in `a` are $a'_1 < \cdots < a'_t$ and their respective multiplicities are $m_1, \cdots, m_t$, then compute $s = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^t \binom{m_k}{2}$.

```
s = 0; m = 1;
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if(a[i] == a[i - 1]) m++;
    else {
        s += m * (m - 1) / 2;
        m = 1;
    }
}
s += m * (m - 1) / 2;
```

The time complexity of this step is $O(n)$.

The overall time complexity is $O(n \ln n)$.

Comment: Thanks, that is quite good but you need to divide the number of pairs satisfying $(1)$ by $\frac{n^2}{2}$ not $\binom{n}{2}$ isn't it? Even same coordinates can be selected.

Comment: If so, the angle of the "segment" formed by two same points with axes is not well-defined. That's why I assume that they're distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are given $N$ points
$$(x_i,y_i)\in{\mathbb Z}^2\qquad(1\leq i\leq N)\ .$$ Introduce new coordinates $(u,v)$ in the plane via 
$$u:=x-y, \qquad v:=x+y\ .$$
You then get $N$ new coordinate pairs $(u_i,v_i)\in{\mathbb Z}^2$. Now check for coinciding $u$-, resp. $v$-coordinates of these points, and take care of the resulting multiplicities. E.g., if you find $4$ points with $u_i=5$ you have to count these coincidences with weight ${4\choose2}=6$ towards the probability you are interested in.

Comment: how is checking for coinciding coordinates done in $ O ( N ) $ operations?

Comment: @MohsenShahriari: Maybe my statement was a blunder. I have deleted it.